# Issue: Violation of Families Policy Requirements (IMEI)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

My app update (from beta to beta) was Rejected.

> We have detected that your app collects personal information, however
>   it was not disclosed in your Play Console. Apps that include children
>   in the target audience must comply with all Families Policy
>   Requirements

I ask for more information, and Google say me that I get device IMEI, but I not get device IMEI.

> we have detected that your app collects personal information
>   (Persistent device identifier - IMEI)

To get IMEI we need "READ_PHONE_STATE" permission, my app not uses this permission and not try to get IMEI in code. Also I checked merged manifest, to check if other lib uses this permission, but is not used.

I ask more info of IMEI and I get response:

> I’m not able to provide any more information or a better answer to
>   your question

Any idea why Google say that my app get IMEI even if I not use?

Libs:

```
implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
implementation 'com.github.JungHsuan:CircularList:1.2.3'
implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'
implementation 'com.github.myinnos:AppIconNameChanger:1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta01'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation 'androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.1'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="apps.base">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


<application
    android:name=".MainApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/DefaultTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" />


    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>



    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.ThemeSelectActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.ConfigurationActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.AppInfoActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.DemoActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.FileListShowActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.FileExplorerActivity" />
    <activity android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:name=".activity.LicencesActivity" />

</application>
```

Comment: Can you show us your AndroidManifest?

Comment: @urukh Updated with manifest.

Comment: Your app show ads?

Comment: No, manifest don´t have Internet permission. App not show adds and not have adds libs like can see in imported libs.